# Ubuntu repositories having problems?

Tags: networking, updates, repository

The Software Updater keeps telling me to "check my network connection" when I check for updates today, Saturday, May 30, 2020.  Does anyone know if there are problems with the repository?

Comment: That could be the case... I mean an issue with the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe there's a problem with the repository. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and when I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I obtain a "Connection not reached" kind of message at the end.
 
If that's the case you'll just have to wait for some while...

Nevertheless you should also make sure your network connection is OK or has nothing to do with it.